# Save to database using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to integrate Hibernate on my code but when I try to save to the database I get:

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

There are no null parameters. Maybe it's because booleans are true of false and database saves 0 and 1?

Model:

```
    private int id;
private String name;
private Boolean hasProfile7;
private Boolean hasWebCSR;
private Boolean hasWebAdmin;
private Boolean hasWebClient;
private String profile7Branch;
private String webCSRBranch;
private String webAdminBranch;
private String webClientBranch;
private String initialDayEnd;
private String finalDayEnd;
private int amountOfDayEnds;
private String user;

//get sets
```

Fetch Data

```
   //Fetch the data from the GeneralSetup Page
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    Boolean hasProfile7 = Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("profile7"));
    Boolean hasWebCSR = Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("webCSR"));
    Boolean hasWebAdmin = Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("webAdmin"));
    Boolean hasWebClient = Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("webClient"));
    String profile7Branch = request.getParameter("profile7Branch");
    String webCSRBranch = request.getParameter("webCSRBranch");
    String webAdminBranch = request.getParameter("webAdminBranch");
    String webClientBranch = request.getParameter("webClientBranch");
    String initialDayEnd = request.getParameter("initialDayEnd");
    String finalDayEnd = request.getParameter("finalDayEnd");
    //TODO calculate amount of day ends based on the date
    int amountOfDayEnds = 7;
    String days = request.getParameter("amountOfDayEnds");
    if (days != null) {
        amountOfDayEnds = Integer.parseInt(days);
    }
    String user = request.getParameter("user");

//Save to database
    Integer gsID = addGeneralSetup(name,hasProfile7,hasWebCSR,hasWebAdmin,hasWebClient,profile7Branch,webCSRBranch,webAdminBranch,webClientBranch,initialDayEnd,finalDayEnd,amountOfDayEnds,user);
```

Save Data

```
public Integer addGeneralSetup(String name, Boolean hasProfile7, Boolean hasWebCSR, Boolean hasWebAdmin,Boolean hasWebClient, String profile7Branch, String webCSRBranch,String webAdminBranch, String webClientBranch,
                               String initialDayEnd, String finalDayEnd, int amountOfDayEnds,String user) {
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    Integer generalSetupID = null;
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        GeneralSetup generalSetup = new GeneralSetup(name,hasProfile7,hasWebCSR,hasWebAdmin,hasWebClient,profile7Branch,webCSRBranch,webAdminBranch,webClientBranch,initialDayEnd,finalDayEnd,amountOfDayEnds,user);
        generalSetupID = (Integer) session.save(generalSetup);
        tx.commit();
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return generalSetupID;

}
```

MySQL table generalsetup:
[image]

Comment: You need to read and post the complete stack trace, containing an explanation of the problem, instead of trying to guess.

Comment: code is incomplete. But few controversial thing exist, for example extremely long parameter list `addGeneralSetup`

Comment: @JacekCz what else can I do?

Comment: @JacekCz what can I do to reduce the parameter list??

Comment: probably I wil create instance earlier and put values directly into fields (without variables). That is not ideal too, OOP fan can discuss long time